# Python learner needs help spotting an error

Tags: python

This piece of code gives a syntax error at the colon of "elif process.loop(i, len(list_i) != 'repeat':" and I can't seem to figure out why.

```
class process:
    def loop(v1, v2):
        if v1 < v2 - 1:
            return 'repeat'
    def isel(chr_i, list_i):
        for i in range(len(list_i)):
            if chr_i == list_i[i]:
                return list_i[i]
            elif process.loop(i, len(list_i) != 'repeat':
                return 'error'()
```

Edit: I am using 3.1.1 by the by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
elif process.loop(i, len(list_i) != 'repeat':
```

you forgot a closed-paren, `)`, just before the `!=`; so the would-be left-hand side of the comparison opens two parentheses but closes only one -- that's the syntax error: "unbalanced parentheses", if you will.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a parentheses!

Change

`elif process.loop(i, len(list_i) != 'repeat':`

to

`elif process.loop(i, len(list_i)) != 'repeat':`